# What connection settings needs to be used in order to connect chat client to server?

Tags: vb.net

So I am playing around in Visual Basic and I'm making a chat client and server. I already did both and tested it on local machine and works. Server listens to connection and records all activities. This is reflected in chat client.

Here's the line of code that I use in order to connect to the "chat server" on same computer.

```
Dim clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888)
```

Anyone know what kind of settings I would need in order to connect remotely to another computer that has the chat server running?

Comment: Well, you'd certainly have to change the IP address.  And possibly the port if that changes.  But the principle of connecting to a server is exactly the same regardless of where the server is.

Comment: This looks like VB.net and not VBA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to change the IP. But the real question is how do you get the IP?

Now if this is just for fun or something, you could just PING the computer if you know the name or walk over to that computer and run something like IPCONFIG on it.

But, in the real world, with a real chat, when a client launches, you would then grab the IP programmatically and post it along with some other info, like the User Name, to a database or web service (which you also created) so other clients would know it is online. You would also need to remove that record or update it with an offline flag or something as well as handle cases where the client looses network connectivity or ends unexpectedly. You can see where I am going with this...

The point is, this needs to be the IP of the client you want to talk to. 127.0.0.1 always refers to the local computer or device.

Comment: I'm somewhat of a noob with networks, sorry!. I tried using the IP from the device that the chat server is running and the chat clients wouldn't connect. (mind you this is all LAN based for now).

So I have Computer A, Computer B and Computer C all connected to the same network. Computer B is running the "chat server" client that is used to listen to thru a port and it records chat activity. Computers A & B have the chat clients. Since I need these clients to look for Computer B (where chat server is running), the IP and Port ( I suppose as well) would be thru ipconfig? did I miss something?

Comment: Firewall? Most standard windows installs have a firewall setup by default, you need to open up the port that you plan on using, looks like 8888 from the above code.